File Not Found error during Docker container run with existing file
I'm trying to deploy a Google Cloud Run application in Python and when the code tries to open a configuration file (yaml) an error occurs saying File Not Found.
However, the file was uploaded during the build phase and the same Python module that tries to open the file is able to find it. See how I tested it:
from rapport_engine.conf.agent import AgentConfiguration
import yaml
import pathlib

def list_files(directory):
    for file in pathlib.Path(directory).rglob('*'):
        if file.is_file():
            print(file)

def load(path: str) -> AgentConfiguration:
    list_files('/etc/rapport_engine')
    with open(path, "r") as f:
        contents = yaml.safe_load(f)
    return AgentConfiguration(contents)

The 'path' argument in the 'load' function says '/etc/rapport_engine/agent.conf.yaml' as it should.
As one can see in the image,the file is shown in the call for the 'list_files' function but when try to open it, got File Not Found error.
Log screenshot
Trying to run the image locally:
The command line is: docker run --env-file .env 15533b9c737e -c /etc/rapport_engine/agent.conf.yaml
It seems to be able to find the configuration (/etc/rapport_engine/agent.conf.yaml) file.
However, I got a new error while trying to connect to Redis. I have a Dockerized Redis running locally but I got a 'Connection refused' error.
I believe it is due to a Docker container cannot use another external container. Is it right?
mauricio@() $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                      NAMES
1497cde1ffc2   redis:7-alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   51 minutes ago   Up 51 minutes   127.0.0.1:6379->6379/tcp   cantegrilforeverbot_redis_1

And the error:
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. Connection refused.

Did you try your container outside Cloud Run?

I did it right now, same error. Here it is:
`
()$ docker run 15533b9c737e
...
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ' /etc/rapport_engine/agent.conf.yaml'
()$ ll /etc/rapport_engine/agent.conf.yaml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2794 Dec  5 07:32 /etc/rapport_engine/agent.conf.yaml
`
The image was built in the GCR and I pulled it locally.
You can see the 'll' command and it shows the file.
I'm sorry, I don't know how to formatting the comments yet. Not easy.

However, running it outside a container (I mean, locally with Python) it works fine.

I've tried replacing ENTRYPOINT by CMD in the Dockerfile. Same error (File not found).
# ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "/opt/rapport_engine" ]
# CMD ["-c /etc/rapport_engine/agent.conf.yaml"]
CMD ["python", "/opt/rapport_engine", "-c /etc/rapport_engine/agent.conf.yaml" ]


I solved it by giving up of using complete path for the configuration file. I still don't know why it doesn't work but I need to go ahead.
So, instead of putting the conf file in some conf directory I put it directly in the project root and reference it simply as ./conf.yaml. Not ideal, but works.
